# How to improve performance of this Javascript/Cracking the code algorithm?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, performance

so here is the question below, with my answer to it. I know that because of the double nested for loop, the efficiency is O(n^2), so I was wondering if there were a way to improve my algorithm/function's big O.

// Design an algorithm and write code to remove the duplicate characters in a string without using any additional buffer. NOTE: One or two additional variables are fine. An extra copy of the array is not.

```
function removeDuplicates(str) {
    let arrayString = str.split("");
    let alphabetArray = [["a", 0],["b",0],["c",0],["d",0],["e",0],["f",0],["g",0],["h",0],["i",0],["j",0],["k",0],["l",0],["m",0],["n",0],["o",0],["p",0],["q",0],["r",0],["s",0],["t",0],["u",0],["v",0],["w",0],["x",0],["y",0],["z",0]]

    for (let i=0; i<arrayString.length; i++) {
        findCharacter(arrayString[i].toLowerCase(), alphabetArray);
    }

    removeCharacter(arrayString, alphabetArray);
};


function findCharacter(character, array) {
    for (let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i][0] === character) {
        array[i][1]++;
        }
    }
} 

function removeCharacter(arrString, arrAlphabet) {
    let finalString = "";
    for (let i=0; i<arrString.length; i++) {
        for (let j=0; j<arrAlphabet.length; j++) {
            if (arrAlphabet[j][1] < 2 && arrString[i].toLowerCase() == arrAlphabet[j][0]) {
            finalString += arrString[i]
            }
        }
      } 
    console.log("The string with removed duplicates is:", finalString)
}

removeDuplicates("Hippotamuus")
```

Comment: You could sort the array first, and then loop through the elements, storing the 'last seen' char as a variable, deleting elements if they are the same, and updating the 'last seen' if they aren't. That way your big O is (n logn) for a comparative sorting algorithm and (n) if you implement a radix sort and map the letters to numbers

Comment: The question mentions "string" and then "array"; so is the input a string or an array? And are we removing consecutive duplicate characters or all duplicates? Also, I don't think a 26-letter array counts as "one or two additional variables"; in fact, you're using a lot of extra space.

Comment: @m69 a 26-letter array is still constant space since it's independent of the length of the input.

Comment: @גלעדברקן It may be constant space, but I don't think that's what's meant by "one or two additional variables are fine". Besides, a two-pointer in-place approach is possible with literally 2 simple variables (providing you get the input as an array of characters).

Comment: @m69 you are offering O(1) space and better than O(n^2) time with an array? How?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I'm not sure the theoretical O(n^2) can be improved upon, but it can be done much simpler (and probably quicker in practice) than the code in the question.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Actually, since the number of characters that you have to check for a duplicate is never more than 26, you could argue that the time complexity is O(N), in the same way that a 26-letter array is constant space.

Comment: @m69 the number of characters could be in the tens of thousands if we allow unicode and all world languages.

Comment: @גלעדברקן That's still a constant :-)

Comment: @m69 theoretically, we could imagine an O(n) alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

The ASCII/Unicode character codes of all letters of the same case are consecutive. This allows for an important optimization: You can find the index of a character in the character count array from its ASCII/Unicode character code. Specifically, the index of the character `c` in the character count array will be `c.charCodeAt(0) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0)`. This allows you to look up and modify the character count in the array in `O(1)` time, which brings the algorithm run-time down to `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I'm assuming the input is a string (which is immutable in javascript) and I'm not sure what exactly does  *"one or two additional variables"* mean so based on your implementation, I'm going to assume it's ok to use O(N) space. To improve time complexity, I think implementations differ according to different requirements for the outputted string.

#### Assumption1: the order of the outputted string is in the order that it appears the first time. eg. "bcabcc" -> "bca"

Suppose the length of s is N, the following implementation uses O(N) space and O(N) time.

```
 function removeDuplicates(s) {
    const set = new Set(); // use set so that insertion and lookup time is o(1)
    let res = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (!set.has(s[i])) {
            set.add(s[i]);
            res += s[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
  }
```

#### Assumption2: the outputted string has to be of ascending order.

You may use **quick-sort** to do in-place sorting and then loop through the sorted array to add the last-seen element to result. Note that you may need to split the string into an array first. So the implementation would use O(N) space and the average time complexity would be O(NlogN)

#### Assumption3: the result is the smallest in lexicographical order among all possible results. eg. "bcabcc" -> "abc"

The following implementation uses O(N) space and O(N) time.

```
const removeDuplicates = function(s) {
    const stack = []; // stack and set are in sync
    const set = new Set(); // use set to make lookup faster
    const lastPos = getLastPos(s);
    let curVal;
    let lastOnStack;

    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        curVal = s[i];
        if (!set.has(curVal)) {
            while(stack.length > 0 && stack[stack.length - 1] > curVal && lastPos[stack[stack.length - 1]] > i) {
                set.delete(stack[stack.length - 1]);
                stack.pop();
            }
            set.add(curVal);
            stack.push(curVal);
        }
    }
    return stack.join('');
};

const getLastPos = (s) => {
    // get the last index of each unique character
    const lastPosMap = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        lastPosMap[s[i]] = i;
    }
    return lastPosMap;
}
```

Comment: I think the correct assumption is that the characters have to stay in the original order, so "hippopotamuses" -> "hipotamuse". Also, a set doesn't really qualify as "one or two variables" imho.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @m69. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There's a little trick to "without using any additional buffer," although I don't see a way to improve on `O(n^2)` complexity without using a hash map to determine if a particular character has been seen. The trick is to traverse the input string buffer (assume it is a JavaScript array since strings in JavaScript are immutable) and overwrite the current character with the next unique character if the current character is a duplicate. Finally, mark the end of the resultant string with a null character.

Pseudocode:

```
i = 1
pointer = 1

while string[i]:
  if not seen(string[i]):
    string[pointer] = string[i]
    pointer = pointer + 1
  i = i + 1

mark string end at pointer
```

The function `seen` could either take `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space or `O(1)` time and `O(|alphabet|)` space if we use a hash map.

Answer (score 1):

I was unsure what was mean't by:

> ...without using any additional buffer.

So I thought I would have a go at doing this in one loop, and let you tell me if it's wrong.

I have worked on the basis that the function you have provided gives the correct output, you were just looking for it to run faster. The function below gives the correct output and run's a lot faster with any large string with lots of duplication that I throw at it.

```js
function removeDuplicates(originalString) {
    let outputString = '';
    let lastChar = '';
    let lastCharOccurences = 1;

    for (let char = 0; char < originalString.length; char++) {
        outputString += originalString[char];

        if (lastChar === originalString[char]) {
            lastCharOccurences++;
            continue;
        }
        
        if (lastCharOccurences > 1) {
            outputString = outputString.slice(0, outputString.length - (lastCharOccurences + 1)) + originalString[char];
            lastCharOccurences = 1;
        }

        lastChar = originalString[char];
    }

    console.log("The string with removed duplicates is:", outputString)
}

removeDuplicates("Hippotamuus")
```

Again, sorry if I have misunderstood the post...